# My saddle support is broken

Tags: guitar, repair

I have an Ovation, and the wood piece attached to the guitar, where the saddle is sitting, has broken appart. Is there any way to get these things fixed (like getting it out of the guitar top, and having it replaced) or will I have to replace the whole guitar top?

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend taking it to a luthier (at your local music shop). They will be able to give the best idea of what needs to be done to fix it, and how much it would cost. then you can decide if the cost is worth it. posting a picture of the issue here would probably get you some better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be fixed and no, you don’t have to replace the whole top. Find a guitar repair person in your area and ask for an estimate.

By the way, that piece of wood is called the *bridge*.

Answer (score 0):

A way to repair it yourself would be to take some super glue and put it on the crack, clamp it together to hold it in place. It is possible to get the bridge off of the guitar top by applying heat to the bridge and slowly prying it off. It is also possible to fit the top with a jig and drill out this cavity for a [replacement](https://portland-guitar.myshopify.com/products/seagull-retrofit-with-split-saddle-bridge).